# Ranging IBeacons stop when switch Bluetooth OFF and ON again

Tags: ionic-framework, bluetooth, ionic3, ibeacon

I'm trying to implement a screen to ranging IBeacons on a Ionic 3.6 project with Ionic Native IBeacons plugin.

This is my code:

```
scanIBeacons(){
    this.ibeacon.requestAlwaysAuthorization();
    this.ibeacon.isBluetoothEnabled().then(isEnabled => {
      console.log("BLUETOOTH ENABLED " + isEnabled)
      this.isBluetooth = isEnabled;
      if(isEnabled){
        if(!this.didRangeBeaconsInRegion) {
          let delegate = this.ibeacon.Delegate();
          this.didRangeBeaconsInRegion = delegate.didRangeBeaconsInRegion()
            .subscribe(
              data => {
                console.log('## didRangeBeaconsInRegion: ' + JSON.stringify(data))
                this.updateUI(data)

              },
              error => console.error()
            );
        }
         //range all my individual beacons
        for(let myBeacon of this.mybeacons){
          this.rangeBeacon(myBeacon.major, myBeacon.minor);
        }
      }
      else{
        if(this.didRangeBeaconsInRegion) 
        this.didRangeBeaconsInRegion.unsubscribe();
        this.didRangeBeaconsInRegion = null;
      //stop range all my individual beacons
        for(let myBeacon of this.mybeacons){
          this.stopRangeBeacon(myBeacon.major, myBeacon.minor);
        }

      }
    })
  }

rangeBeacon(major:number, minor:number){

    let beaconRegion = this.ibeacon.BeaconRegion(major + "-" + minor,'UUID',major, minor);

    this.ibeacon.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(beaconRegion)
      .then(
        () => console.log('%%%%%%Native layer recieved the request to ranging%%%%%%'),
        error => console.error('%%%%%%Native layer failed to begin ranging%%%%%%: ', error)
      );
  }

  stopRangeBeacon(major:number, minor:number){

    let beaconRegion = this.ibeacon.BeaconRegion(major + "-" + minor,'UUID',major, minor);

    this.ibeacon.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(beaconRegion)
      .then(
        () => console.log('%%%%%%Native layer recieved the request to ranging%%%%%%'),
        error => console.error('%%%%%%Native layer failed to begin ranging%%%%%%: ', error)
      );
  }
```

If I start the aplication with the bluetooth activated it start to ranging correctly IBeacons but when I push de bluetooth toggle to switch off and on again it stop to ranging, it still receiving ranging events but with the beacons array is empty. The only way to solve is close completely the app and open it again.

I have already tried to remove the ranging listener, stop all ranging to add and start it all again and not work.

If I start the app with the bluetooth off and then switch on in this case works correctly.

What would be doing wrong?

EDIT:This problem only occurs on android 7